# How to run mapreduce samples using jar file?

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I am trying to run mapreduce samples  such as Bellard ,LongLong, Montgomery,Summation,DistributedPentomino ,OneSidedPentomino usi such as Bellard ,LongLong, Montgomery,Summation,DistributedPentomino ,OneSidedPentomino using hadoop mapresuce example jar. Can anyone please tell me the command to run these samples using jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is exact chapter from HortonWorks about Hadoop MapReduce out of the box examples. It is part of their guide.

[Running MapReduce examples on Hadoop YARN.](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/running_mapreduce_examples_on_yarn.html)

Another. more straightforward short article but without too much details:

[Run Sample MapReduce Examples](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2190194&seqNum=3)

In fact, having Hadoop version XXX you need:

```
export YARN_EXAMPLES=$YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce
yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-XXX.jar
```

Please check your actual path.